# How to total number of Special Numbers between two Numbers X and Y

Tags: algorithm

In a game where you are given two 
integers (X and Y), and you have to print the number of special 
numbers between X and Y both inclusive.

The property of a special numbers is as follows:
 A special number is not divisible by any number of the form Z*Z where (Z>1).

> Input: 
>       T, the number of testcases. Each testcase consists of two space separated integers      denoting X and Y.
>
> ```
> Output: The required answer in one line for each testcase.
>
> Constraints: 
> 1 <= T <= 100 
> 1 <= X,Y <= 10^9 
> 0 <= |X-Y| <= 10^6
> ```

My problem is that when i try to count all numbers  out of memory error comes. and time limit is 3 seconds can some one suggest an efficient algorithm for this?

```
i have wriiten the code like this:
    public class GameOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameOfNumbers g=new GameOfNumbers();
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int tc=s.nextInt();           //no of test cases
    for(int i=1;i<=tc;i++){        // for each test case.
    int x=s.nextInt();              // range 1(lower)
    int y=s.nextInt();              // range 2(upper)
    g.countSpecialNumbers(x,y);
    }

    }

    private  void countSpecialNumbers(int x, int y) {
        int arr_nums[]=new int[y-x+1];
        int z=0,l=x,count=0;
        while(z<arr_nums.length){
            arr_nums[z]=l++;
            z++;
        }
        int c=(int)Math.sqrt(y);
        for(int i=2;i<=c;i++){
            for(int k=0;k<arr_nums.length;k++){if(arr_nums[k] !=-1 && arr_nums[k]%(i*i) == 0){arr_nums[k]=-1;}}
        }
        for(int k=0;k<arr_nums.length;k++){if(arr_nums[k] !=-1)count++;}
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code that results in the error you mention. We can not tell you what causes the out of memory error out of the blue

Comment: Note that these "special" numbers are called [square-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_number).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that according to the statement you need no count all the numbers between 1000 and 10^9. In each test case you will need to count the numbers only in a fixed interval of length no more than 10^6(see last constraint).

And another optimization you can include - you need to only iterate over the prime numbers not greater than the square root of `Y`(try to figure out **why**). You can precompute the list of prime numbers less than `sqrt` of 10^9 and iterate only over them.

Comment: @SamyArous the original version of the question included that OP gets memory error when counting the numbers between 1000 and 10^9. This is an invalid case and I explicitly say so in the first part of my answer. Also even now the question says: `My problem is that when i try to count all numbers out of memory error comes`

Answer (score 0):

I can see, 3 ways you can optimize your code:

1. You should not create an array with all the numbers between X and Y, that makes no sense. Simply loop from X to Y (This is BTW what is causing your memory shortage)
2. You don't need to test all the numbers smaller than the square root of C, you only need to test prime numbers up to the square root of C
3. As a shortcut, always try and see if square root of C is not an integer (that means that C = int(sqrt(C)²))
4. Another shortcut, would be to search C in the list of prime numbers. This would be done in log(n) using binary search.

Good luck with the implementation.

Comment: 1. Regarding point 2, why only worry about prime numbers. A number in the range could be divisible by np*np, where np is non-prime number. 2. How would step 3 help? What is C in your comment, where range is X to Y. 3. How to compute a list of primes less than say a number N.